# Check if a list of objects contain a specified object java

Tags: java, list, object, contains

Suppose there are few classes all extending an abstract class abc :-

```
public class mno extends abc { ... }
public class pqr extends abc { ... }
public class xyz extends abc { ... }
```

there is a list of objects which contains object of these class.

```
List<abc> f =new ArrayList<abc>();
f.add(new mno());
f.add(new pqr());
f.add(new xyz());
```

Is there a way to check if list f *contains an object of* class xyz and *remove it from* the list.

I tried f.contains(xyz.class) or f.contains(new xyz()) but it returned flase

Comment: LOOKUP instanceOf keyword

Comment: I have to wonder if this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you may be better off using a completely different approach, such as a different collection or collections.

Comment: And beyond that : read about java coding conventions. Class names start upper case. Always.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for pointing the issue, have started reading clean code by Robert Martin, and have realized my mistake after reading two chapters.

Comment: You are very welcome. That is rare feedback...

Answer (score 4):

If you use java 8 you can do it:

```
f.removeIf(xyz.class::isInstance);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java 8 Streams.

```
List<abc> newList = new ArrayList<>(f)
            .stream()
            .filter(xyz.class::isInstance)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `instanceof` operator to check that an object is of specific type as shown below:

```
 Iterator<abc> iterator = f.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
       if(iterator.next() instanceof xyz) {
           iterator.remove();
       }
   }
```

Also, the above code uses [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to safely remove the objects from the list.

Also, I strongly suggest you follow the Java naming conventions for class, variable, etc. as your example class names abc, xyz, etc. are very poor.